# Is there a way to get the country code according to their calling number

Tags: flutter, dart, intl

I was trying to get a country's 2 letter code using the calling code.

For example it would be getting the Country Code 'MY' from its calling code '+60'

I want to use it to set the initialcountryvalue for intlphonefield.

Is there a way to do that in flutter?

Comment: libphonenumber: https://github.com/google/libphonenumber https://pub.dev/packages/libphonenumber

Comment: Do you have any code or examples of what exactly you're working with? It would be simple to just keep a map of calling codes to country codes and then look up the calling code - unless there's something I'm missing. Hard to determine without any real context.

Comment: I was using intlphonefield but I need to read some data that contains a phone number eg: +60xxxxxxxxxx so I want to read the +60 part and insert it into the phonefield.
But the phonefield only accepts 2 letter country code such as 'MY' for Malaysia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package [country_code_picker](https://fluttercore.com/flutter-country-code-picker/).
Also there is [country_picker 2.0.16](https://pub.dev/packages/country_picker) from where you can pick code too.

Usage:

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
     body: new Center(
       child: new CountryCodePicker(
         onChanged: print,
         // Initial selection and favorite can be one of code ('IT') OR dial_code('+39')
         initialSelection: 'IT',
         favorite: ['+39','FR'],
         // optional. Shows only country name and flag
         showCountryOnly: false,
         // optional. Shows only country name and flag when popup is closed.
         showOnlyCountryWhenClosed: false,
         // optional. aligns the flag and the Text left
         alignLeft: false,
       ),
     ),
 );
```

To get the country code:

```
void _onCountryChange(CountryCode countryCode) {
    //Todo : manipulate the selected country code here
    print("New Country selected: " + countryCode.toString());
  }
```

Comment: Er is there a way to like get the country from using the code? Cause I think these have to be manually chosen right?

Comment: You can use this package to get Flag of any country , Phone number Code of any country and Name of any country.

Comment: No no no I mean I have to find the country code using the phone number... not select it

Comment: You can also get either Full country name or County code,  Please refer the link .